# Unioning select statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am trying to union 2 queries that I am running in SQL

Here is the code:

```
SELECT DATEPART(dw,t1.Date) AS D1, 
DATENAME(dw,t1.Date) AS Day_of_Week,
AVG (T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec) AS Infl_AHT
from bm.t1agent t1 with (nolock)
JOIN prc.Route rreq
on t1.id = rreq.ID
join PRC.Routing rraw with (nolock) 
on rreq.ID = rraw.Id
where t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
AND rreq.Influenced=1
GROUP BY  ROLLUP ((DATEPART(dw,t1.Date),DATENAME(dw,t1.Date)))

Union ALL

select DATEPART(dw,t1.Date) AS D1, 
DATENAME(dw,t1.Date) AS Day_of_Week,
AVG (T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec) AS Non_inf_AHT
from bm.t1agent t1 with (nolock)
JOIN prc.Route rreq
on t1.id = rreq.t1CallID
join PRC.Routing rraw with (nolock) 
on rreq.ID = rraw.Id
where t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
AND rreq.Influenced=0
GROUP BY  ROLLUP ((DATEPART(dw,t1.Date),DATENAME(dw,t1.Date)))

ORDER BY D1
```

However, when I do this its not exactly creating the output that I want

Output:

```
D1  Day_of_Week Infl_AHT
1   Sunday  207.783300685602
1   Sunday  245.439166666667
2   Monday  224.625025938991
2   Monday  261.060339364923
```

But the output should be broken out more. It should read

```
D1  Day_of_Week Infl_AHT            Non_infl_AHT
1   Sunday    207.783300685602  245.439166666667
2   Monday    224.625025938991  261.060339364923
```

Should I try to create tables and then join this or is it actually possible to union the select statements?

Comment: You won't be able to get the expected output with a single `UNION` - you need to select that column and do a join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this in a single query using `conditional aggregate`.
Try this.

```
SELECT Datepart(dw, t1.Date) AS D1,
       Datename(dw, t1.Date) AS Day_of_Week,
       Avg (CASE WHEN rreq.Influenced = 1 THEN T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec END) Infl_AHT,
       Avg (CASE WHEN rreq.Influenced = 0 THEN T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec END) Non_inf_AHT
FROM   bm.t1agent t1 WITH (nolock)
       JOIN prc.Route rreq
         ON t1.id = rreq.ID
       JOIN PRC.Routing rraw WITH (nolock)
         ON rreq.ID = rraw.Id
WHERE  t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
GROUP  BY ROLLUP (( Datepart(dw, t1.Date), Datename(dw, t1.Date) ))
```

Comment: Nice! You might want to mention that because nothing is projected from the unmatched CASE (i.e. no ELSE value), that a NULL is returned and [that most aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) (including AVG) ignore null values in the aggregate and thus the average calculation isn't distorted / diluted by the unmatched case condition.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` is something like a vertical join. It brings together queries that have the same content in their fields.

What you are looking to do is horizontally join two queries with different fields, which would be accomplished by a standard `JOIN` on your D1 or Day_of_of_Week fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely creating the output correctly. Just that in union statement output the alias for corresponding match column that appears first is displayed in the output. Please see the following statement:

```
select sysdate as a1 from dual
union all
select sysdate as a2 from dual;
```

Please notice that in the output the column name is a1 (although you aliased it a2 for the second select statement).

Also notice that date is displayed in two different rows in result set (even though the values of sysdate are same). If you use UNION instead of UNION all, all duplicate columns are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

This is way clumsier than NoDisplayName's solution, I'm just demonstrating an alternative way of doing it. By adding a "dummy" column for the aggregate function in each of the union parts, you can get a different average column per part. I moved the rollup to the outer level:

```
select D1, Day_of_Week, max(Infl_AHT), max(Non_inf_AHT)
from (
    SELECT DATEPART(dw,t1.Date) AS D1, 
        DATENAME(dw,t1.Date) AS Day_of_Week,
        AVG (T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec) AS Infl_AHT,
        -- add dummy column
        null as Non_inf_AHT
    from bm.t1agent t1 with (nolock)
    JOIN prc.Route rreq
        on t1.id = rreq.ID
    join PRC.Routing rraw with (nolock) 
        on rreq.ID = rraw.Id
    where t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
    AND rreq.Influenced=1
    GROUP BY DATEPART(dw,t1.Date), DATENAME(dw,t1.Date)
    Union ALL
    select DATEPART(dw,t1.Date) AS D1, 
        DATENAME(dw,t1.Date) AS Day_of_Week,
        -- add dummy column
        null as Infl_AHT,
        AVG (T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec) AS Non_inf_AHT
    from bm.t1agent t1 with (nolock)
    JOIN prc.Route rreq
        on t1.id = rreq.t1CallID
    join PRC.Routing rraw with (nolock) 
        on rreq.ID = rraw.Id
    where t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
    AND rreq.Influenced=0
    GROUP BY DATEPART(dw,t1.Date), DATENAME(dw,t1.Date)
)
GROUP BY  ROLLUP (D1, Day_of_Week)
ORDER BY D1;
```